# Помогите написать код как можно короче

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

Напишите код как можно короче :

```html
if (localStorage == null){
    saveComments()
}
function saveComments(){
    var textAlert = document.getElementById("key1").value;
document.getElementById("key2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("key1").value;
    localStorage.setItem("key3", textAlert)
}

showComments()
function showComments(){
    let placeHome = document.getElementById('key2');
    let out = '';
        out += localStorage.getItem("key3") 
    placeHome.innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: Такие записи "document.getElementById('key2')", где идет обращение к идентификатору, можно вызывать как key2. Это будет сразу получение объекта. Т.е. можно вызывать его свойства как key2.innerHTML.

Comment: @OlegDmitrochenko: между этими подходами есть нюансы.

Comment: `localStorage.key3 = key2.innerHTML = key1.value;` x) Другое дело, что localStorage не может быть null... В коде изначально ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

Если не [критично](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom#document-getelementbyid-ili-prosto-id) использование `getElementById()`, то коротко будет так:

```js
if (!localStorage) { saveComments() }

function saveComments() { key2.innerHTML = localStorage["key3"] = key1.value; }

showComments()

function showComments() { key2.innerHTML = localStorage["key3"]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const saveComments = () => document.getElementById("key2").innerHTML = localStorage['key3'] = document.getElementById("key1").value;

(!localStorage) && saveComments()

const showComments = (() => document.getElementById('key2').innerHTML = localStorage['key3'])()
```

Comment: `saveComments is not defined` ) Стрелочные функции не всплывают, их нужно объявлять до использования.